# What is the LED in Audio port for?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, unix

I recently attempted to install Ubuntu on may `Late 2013 13" Mac Book Pro with Retina Display`.

Under Linux I noticed a **Red** LED light inside the audio port. It looks like Ubuntu doesn't know how to handle it and activated it.

I have absolutely no idea what is that for, but I would really like to know.

Also is there any way to control it? : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the the digital audio out built into that port. You can plug in a toslink cable instead of a 1/8th inch analog cable to get digital audio from your Mac Book. ([via](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3676))

*might not work in Ubuntu*

Comment: Nice! I didn't knew I had an optical audio output.